# I have a script of adding watermark on single image but i have 5 image what can I do?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, watermark

I have a script of adding watermark on single image but i have 5 image what can I do?

```
<?php

   if(isset($_FILES['image_file']))
{
    $max_size = 800; //max image size in Pixels
    $destination_folder = 'images';
    $watermark_png_file = 'watermark.png'; //path to watermark image
    
    $image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
    $image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size']; //file size
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp
    $image_type = $_FILES['image_file']['type']; //file type

    switch(strtolower($image_type)){ //determine uploaded image type 
            //Create new image from file
            case 'image/png': 
                $image_resource =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
                break;
            case 'image/gif
```

- List item

':
$image_resource =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp);
break;
case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
$image_resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
break;
default:
$image_resource = false;
}

```
    if($image_resource){
        //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($image_temp);
        
        //Construct a proportional size of new image
        $image_scale        = min($max_size / $img_width, $max_size / $img_height); 
        $new_image_width    = ceil($image_scale * $img_width);
        $new_image_height   = ceil($image_scale * $img_height);
        $new_canvas         = imagecreatetruecolor($new_image_width , $new_image_height);

        //Resize image with new height and width
        if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $image_resource , 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_image_width, $new_image_height, $img_width, $img_height))
        {
            
            if(!is_dir($destination_folder)){ 
                mkdir($destination_folder);//create dir if it doesn't exist
            }
            
            //calculate center position of watermark image
            $watermark_left = ($new_image_width/2)-(300/2); //watermark left
            $watermark_bottom = ($new_image_height/2)-(100/2); //watermark bottom

            $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_png_file); //watermark image

            //use PHP imagecopy() to merge two images.
            imagecopy($new_canvas, $watermark, $watermark_left, $watermark_bottom, 0, 0, 300, 100); //merge image
            
            //output image direcly on the browser.
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($new_canvas, NULL , 90);
            
            //Or Save image to the folder
            //imagejpeg($new_canvas, $destination_folder.'/'.$image_name , 90);
            
            //free up memory
            imagedestroy($new_canvas); 
            imagedestroy($image_resource);
            die();
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>
   <body>
      
      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image_file" /><br>
         <input type = "file" name = "image_file" />
  <input type = "file" name = "image_file" /><br>
         <input type = "file" name = "image_file" />
  <input type = "file" name = "image_file" /><br>
      
         <input type = "submit"  value="submit" name="submit"/>         
      </form>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

- List item

Comment: Either use multiple file inputs **(with different names)** or use one input where you allow to select multiple files. On server side loop over the recieved files and run it through your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use 5 different names for the 5 different images in the form part.

```
<form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image_file1" /><br>
         <input type = "file" name = "image_file2" />
  <input type = "file" name = "image_file3" /><br>
         <input type = "file" name = "image_file4" />
  <input type = "file" name = "image_file5" /><br>
      
         <input type = "submit"  value="submit" name="submit"/>         
      </form>
```

and, in your php part (adding watermark) run on all of the codes of the 5 different names images, one by one:

apply the codes but change the names to
$_FILES['image_file1'],$_FILES['image_file2'],
$_FILES['image_file3'], $_FILES['image_file4'], $_FILES['image_file5'] .... and so on.